# Does anybody know why the icons within my buttons refuse to center?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I know this is a minor issue, but you may notice that the icons (that I pulled off of react-icons) are slightly lifted up within the buttons. How could I put them right in the middle?

Thats my only question but it won't let me post that alone because my post it mostly code so here's more words. What a stupid feature.

[image: misaligned icons]

Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BsFillPersonFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { FiMail } from 'react-icons/fi';
import { FaPlus, FaSearch } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiTwotoneBell, AiOutlineSearch } from 'react-icons/ai';
import './navbar.css';
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="homeBtn">VIZZEY</h2>
        <div className="search">   
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search" className="form-control" />
          <button className="searchBtn"><AiOutlineSearch/></button>
        </div>
        <ul className="ugh-buttons">
          <li className="btn">
            <button className="icon-btn">
              <FiMail/></button>
          </li>
          <li className="btn">
            <button className="icon-btn"><FaPlus/></button>
          </li>
          <li className="btn">
            <button className="icon-btn"><AiTwotoneBell/></button>
          </li>
          <li className="btn">
            <button className="icon-btn"><BsFillPersonFill/></button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
export default Navbar;
```

navbar.css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }

ul {
    list-style: none; 
    display: flex;
} 

a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #fff;
} 

.homeBtn {
    text-align: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    padding-left: 25%; 
    color:#00ce7f; 
}

#nav-bar {
    background-color: #626466;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
    align-items: center; 
    height: 55px;
} 

.form-control {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);  
    border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important; 
    height: 38px; 
    width: 70%; 
    border: none; 
    padding-left: 10px;   
    font-size: 20px; 
}   


.search { 
    padding-left: 15%;  
}

.btn { 
    padding-right: 10px; 
} 

.ugh-buttons {
padding-right: 20px; 
}

.icon-btn {
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    color: white; 
    border: none;  
    font-size: x-large; 
    
}


button:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
    background-color: rgb(111, 0, 255);
} 

button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
} 

.searchBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    height: 38px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    width: 40px;   
    border: none;    
    font-size: large; 
  
}       

.buttons {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00ce7f;
    height: 38px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; 
    width: 40px;   
    border: none; 
}
 
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

input {
    outline: none; 
}
```

Comment: Set line-height! :) Fun fix in fire-fox and other platforms, like safari/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your css:

```
button[class*="icon-"],
button.searchBtn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This should center you're icon inside the button. If this doesn't work maybe check the size of the icon in F12 browser mode. Sometimes there are icons which does look like there having the same height and width, but they don't.

Another solution would be using `position: absolute` trick

```
button[class*="icon-"],
button.searchBtn {
    position: relative;
}

button[class*="icon-"] > svg,
button.searchBtn > svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Hope this works for you :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of changing so many things. Since you're using `display flex` for the parent, the elements position themselves next to each other. In order to make them take equal space (I think that's what you want) you need to use `flex wrap` for the children.

```
ul {
display:flex;
}

li {
flex-wrap: 1;
}
```